# Тонкости использования переменных Java состоящих из других переменных

Tags: java, инициализация

Заметил следующий нюанс при работе с переменными в Java,

характерно для любых типов переменных int, String и т.д., не

зависит от модификатора - переменная static или не статическая:

```
public class Test {
    static int var1 = 5;
    static int var2 = 5;
    static int var3 = 5;
    static int varSum = var1 + var2 + var3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(varSum);
        var1 = 50;
        System.out.println(varSum);
    }
}
```

Результат исполнения будет:

`15`
`15`

Хотя, казалось бы, что должно быть:

`15`
`60`

Вопросы следующие:

1. Получается переменную, состоящую из других переменных нужно

переинициализировать каждый раз после изменения одной из её

составляющих? В данном случае после присвоения var1 = 50; нужно

будет вставить `varSum = var1 + var2 + var3;` тогда результат будет

15 и 60.

2. Может быть, есть какой-то метод заставляющий переменную varSum

пересчитать себя без переинициализации? Например:

`varSum.something()` или `something(varSum)` или ещё как-то?

Вопрос возник при реализации более сложной задачи, здесь я его просто максимально упростил чтобы передать суть вопроса.

Comment: То что вы описали называется реактивное программирование https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 Изначально Java не реактивные язык программирования, но для Java есть, например, библиотека https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava которая позволяет делать подобные вещи.

Comment: В вашем коде, фактически переменная `varSum` не состоит из других переменных как вы думаете. Там просто храниться число 15 и не более того.

Comment: В вашем примере написана глупость. Статические переменные класса никак не участвуют в работе метода, т.к. внутри него существую свои переменные с такими же названиями (элементарная область видимости переменных). Опиши подробнее в чём ваша загвоздка? Если вам необходимо иметь эту переменную с реальным её содержимым вне зависимости от экземпляра класса, то тогда она должна иметь модификатор **volatile**. Ну а так вообще непонятно, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Rootware, спасибо за поправку - действительно лишнего накопировал в пост. Сейчас убрал лишнее, думаю теперь понятнее станет

Answer (score 6):

Выражение `varSum = var1 + var2 + var3` вычисляется как только программа доходит до данной строки, а в `int varSum` хранится только число типа `int`(4 байта) и больше ничего. На строке `var1 = 50` значение переменной `var1`(также 4 байта) перезаписываются на значение `50`, больше присваивание нового значения ничего не делает

Comment: Ну, то есть единственный выход - пересчитать varSum? Или есть другой путь?

Comment: @DonDroid да, придется пересчитать

Comment: блин, случайно удалил комментарий от Igor Golovin про реактивное программирование и библиотеку для Java

Comment: @DonDroid есть другие пути, что бы формула вычислялась используя текущие значения переменных

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, подскажите какие?

Answer (score 4):

Переменная `varSum` не состоит из трех переменных `var1, var2, var3`. Она является значением суммы трех переменных на момент выполнения операции.

Проще говоря, по очереди выполнились все действия, которые вы написали:

1) Инициализация `var1, var2, var3`

2) Вычисление суммы значений этих переменных `var1 + var2 + var3`

3) Присваивание результата суммы переменной `varSum`

4) Вывод значения `varSum` на экран

5) Изменение значения `var1`

6) Снова вывод суммы `varSum`

Соответственно, если необходимо пересчитать значение `varSum`, надо выполнить это расчет еще раз после изменения значения `var1`.